# Android parse.com check if object exists

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm meeting a problem in my current app, the app containt following/follower system, when I look to user profil I want to retrieve an information if I'm already following this user or not. this is my code

```
private class CheckinIfFollowing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                     //preexcution
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Follow");
                    query.whereEqualTo("from", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    query.whereEqualTo("to", userId);
                    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                            if(e==null){
                                Toast.makeText(UserProfil.this, "blue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //btn_follow.setButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bleu));
                            }else{
                            if(e.getCode() == ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND)
                                  {
                                Toast.makeText(UserProfil.this, "pink", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //btn_follow.setButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink));  
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                  //unknown error, debug
                                  }
                                 }


                        }
                    });

            return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                //  followingButton(AlreadyFollowing);
                //  btn_follow.setClickable(true);
                }
                }
```

I'm executing the AsyncTask but nothing shown in the screen.

Btw the "from" and "to" column of the Follow class in parse.com are pointers to _User.

Comment: isn't ParseQuery already Asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

First of all (that's not directly related to your issue, just an observatino): if you're using `<something>InBackground` method of a query, you don't have to put it inside an `AsyncTask`. It's already being executed in the background. In your case, you are basically (simplifying a bit here) executing an async task from an async task.

---

Although you didn't say what's stored in the `userId` object, I'm assuming (based on it's name) it's an `objectId` of a `ParseUser` object and **not** a `ParseUser` object itself. And I believe that's a reason for your issue. This line to be exact:

```
query.whereEqualTo("to", userId);
```

You said:

> Btw the "from" and "to" column of the Follow class in parse.com are
>   pointers to _User.

If you're storing `Pointer` to another `ParseObject` you should probably be passing this type of an object if you're using this field in a query (and **not** an `objectId` - `String`). So in your case you should be passing an instance of `ParseUser` instead of its `objectId`.

You can use [`createWithoutData`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#createWithoutData(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) method of `ParseObject` to create an object (with `objectId`) that you can use for your query.